# Find and replace parts of matched string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have something in a text file that looks like `'%r'%XXXX`, where the `XXXX` represents some name at the end. Examples include `'%r'%addR` or `'%r'%removeA`. I can match these patterns using regex `'%r'%\w+`. What I would like to replace this with is `'{!r}'.format(XXXX)`. Note that the name has to stay the same in the replace so I'd get `'{!r}.format(addR)` or `'{!r}.format(removeA)`. Is there a way to replace parts of the matched string in this way while retaining the unknown variable name pulled out with `\w+` in the regex search?

I'm specifically looking for a solution using the find and replace features in Notepad++.

Comment: Is `'%r'%XXXX` an entire line?  If not, describe the context.  Does `'%r'%XXXX` appear more than once in a line?

Comment: You need capturing groups + backreferences.

Comment: @Smandoli The text can be located inside a line and more than one may be in a line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
'%r'%(\w+)
```

and replace with `'{!r}.format\(\1\)`

The `'%r'%(\w+)` pattern contains a pair of unescaped parentheses that create a capturing group. Inside the replacement pattern, we use a `\1` backreference to restore that value.

**NOTE**: The `(` and `)` in the replacement *must be escaped* because otherwise they are treated as Boost conditional replacement pattern functional characters.

See more on [**capturing groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search on:

```
'%r'%(XXXX)
```

Replace with:

```
Whatever You like \1
```

`\1` will match the first set of grouping parentheses.